# Is the `position` property dropped in CSS 3?

Tags: css, css-position

I contacted the support of a mayor IDE, after the CSS property `position` didn't "auto-complete" in the latest version. They said it doesn't exist in CSS 3. I did some digging, and replied

> "CSS Level 3 builds on CSS Level 2 module by module, using the CSS2.1
>   specification as its core. Each module adds functionality and/or
>   replaces part of the CSS2.1 specification."
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/NOTE-css-2010-20110512/#css3
>
> Additionally, this defines the position property, although it's not
>   finished: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs#positioning

But they stood their ground. This is a reply from them, after a length debate.

> [..] there are indeed many properties in CSS3 which are copied 1:1 from
>   CSS2.1. Among new properties introduced in CSS3, you can find many CSS
>   2.1 definitions in CSS3 draft. Unfortunately, it's not the case with
>   position and some other properties [..]

I have no grudge towards them, but am curious. Does `position` really not exist in CSS 3?

Comment: It is valid CSS3, albeit not new to it.

Comment: There is a totally different `position` property documented in the [Template Layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-layout/#position) too; however the CSS2 property still validates as CSS3 anyway.

Comment: They're entirely confused about what CSS2 and CSS3 are, you should consider using a different IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may not exist in the new Spec (which is TBD), it remains valid.

I ran this through the validator at CSS3 level and it was all good

```
.jason{
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Look at this Quick Reference Guide compiled by Chris Hanscom. You'll find the positioning spec at the bottom of the right hand column on the second page

http://www.veign.com/downloads/guides/qrg0008.pdf

Comment: Great cheat sheet, thanks. But as it is user compiled I wouldn't use it as "evidence".

Answer (score 1):

Although from last year, the snapshot of css3 state contains `position` poperty. As stated before, it is the same well know `position` that in css 2.1. As far as I know css3 doesn't "forbid" anything introduced in previous versions.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/#properties (scroll down to table)

Comment: That table doesn't contain any CSS 3 properties?

Comment: Good resource though, thank you! `The CSS Working Group intends that the new CSS modules will not contradict the CSS2.1 specification: only that they will add functionality and refine definitions` That says it all I think.